# Is there a way to modify the Windows 8 installation disc?

Tags: windows-8, updates

Is there a way to modify the Windows 8 installation disc?

I'm trying to include some updates and language pack to my Windows 8 installation disk as I did in Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

This works the same way like in Windows 7. Mount the install.wim with DISM and use DISM to add the Updates and Updates. Now unmount the WIM again.

Comment: A link to Windows 8 TechNet DISM usage: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825239.aspx